# Plotting date and currency and convert the date to a readable format

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to write a python 3 code that can take the data that I found on a website and convert it into a graph that I want to analyze using Pandas. the data looks like this

[1533103200000,7200],[1535781600000,7547],[1538373600000,7250],[1541052000000,7684],[1543647600000,8499],[1546326000000,8150],[1549004400000,8600],[1551423600000,9250],[1554098400000,11545],[1556690400000,10444],[1561766400000,8697]

each piece of data in the brackets is a plot point. The X (left) coordinate is the date in unicode and the Y (right) coordinate is the price.

I have tried basic plot charting, but it keeps telling me that I cant convert the string to float

x, y = np.loadtxt('data.txt', delimiter=']''[', unpack=True)
    plt.plot(x,y, label='Loaded from file!')

```
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.title('Interesting Graph\nCheck it out')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

How do I take that data and put it into a format that pandas can recognize?

How can I make those pieces of data into what I want? (date, currency)?

Comment: What does it have to do with Unicode? It's a text encoding format, so "the date in Unicode" doesn't make much sense given that the date is an integer (or is it? it looks like all the dates are zeros anyway).

Comment: I think what you actually want to ask is "how do I convert the following values from their current format into valid dates?".  
Once you have a series with valid dates then everything else should be straightforward.

Comment: To clarify, the large number is the date and the small number is the currency. Ignoring that  currencies are zero (because I do have plots that are positive)

And yes - I do want to convert this to date and currency so that I can plug them into a graph and analyze the data. I really apologize for my noobness as I'm just starting out with Python and have just a basic understanding of the language.